# redirect path not found

Tags: python, django

I wanted the user to be able to make a new blog and after he makes the blog he should be redirected to the detailed view of the blog, however I feel there is some problem with the `get_absolute_url` and in the `urls` code is given below

---

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import PostCreateView

urlpatterns=[
path('',views.BlogsList.as_view(),name='blog-home'),
path('<int:blog_id>/like/', views.like_post, name='like_post'),
path('post/<int:id>/', views.post_detail, name='post-detail'),
path('post/new/',PostCreateView.as_view(),name='post-create'),
]
```

---

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse 

class Blog(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content=models.TextField()
    date_posted=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='likes',blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(blog_id):
        return reverse('post-detail',args=[str(blog_id)])
```

---

views.py(shortened)

```
class BlogsList(ListView):
    model=Blog
    template_name='blog/home.html'
    context_object_name='blogs'
    ordering=['-date_posted']




def post_detail(request, id):
    post=get_object_or_404(Blog, id=id)
    comments=comment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('-id')

    if request.method=="POST":
        comment_form=CommentForm(request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            content=request.POST.get('content')
            new_comment=comment.objects.create(post=post, user=request.user, content=content)
            new_comment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(Blog.get_absolute_url(blog_id=id))
    else:
        comment_form= CommentForm()     

    context={
        'post':post,
        'is_liked': post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists(), 
        'comments':comments,
        'comment_form':comment_form,
        }
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html',context)
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
model=Blog
fields=['title','content']

def form_valid(self,form):
    form.instance.author=self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(Blog.get_absolute_url())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get_absolute_url` method takes a single argument. You have used `blog_id`, but usually in Python we use `self`.

In the method, `self` is the blog instance that you want to return the id of. You can get this with `self.id` or `self.pk`.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', args=[self.pk])
```